# Detect if text field is empty or not and trigger code once, unless the state changes

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

I want to detect if this text field is empty or not and then run some code based on that.

**Question is:** how can I run the code only once ...and then run it once again each and every time  that the state of the text field changes during one `focus`

- Different states being `empty` or `not empty`.

---

**To further elaborate:**

( The most important part in these jsfiddle's are shown in the console. )

- [Here is a jsfiddle of a code](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/LncWS/) that executes the code every
  time you keyup (Not what I want. Just the initial code. ).

  ```
  $('input').on("keyup", function() {

      var val = $(this).attr('value'),
          previous = $(this).prev();

      if ( val === '' ) {
          console.log('Empty');
      }
      else if ( val !== '' ) {
          console.log('Text');
      }

  });
  ```
- and [Here is a jsfiddle of a code](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/LncWS/1/) that executes the code once 
  per focus (This is somewhat near to what I want).

  **What it is still missing, and what I can't seem to get done, is to basically run the code once again each and every time that the state
  changes during that one focus.** How could I do that?

  ```
  $('input').on("focus", function() {

      $('input').one("keyup", function() {

          var val = $(this).attr('value'),
              previous = $(this).prev();

          if ( val === '' ) {
              console.log('Empty');
          }
          else if ( val !== '' ) {
              console.log('Text');
          }

      });

  });
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a plugin called jQuery Text Change from ZURB. Does everything you want and more, also has a trigger action called 'hastext' and 'notext', take a look at:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

there are also demos there.

I made this for you (using that plugin).

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/UtwNz/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I would perhaps use this plugin, but I'd rather not.

Comment: @Lollero Do you have a particular reason? :-)

Comment: Well, for the obvious reasons. I want to have a code that does what I want and nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: I don't know.. I changed my mind.. I mean, I'm not going to use the plugin cause I got far better idea to fit my needs, but as far as solutions go, plugin that does exactly what is needed, is always a good one. So, I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Lollero I understood. Well, just to know, this is not a heavy plugin with lots of methods, it just has few ones. The idea is to repurpose and write less code :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a hold of the value of the field, and only trigger if the value's state has changed: http://jsfiddle.net/xk6A5/9/